# gatling response give me error message?

Tags: load-testing, gatling, web-traffic

Gatling senario is

```
  val scn = scenario("First Test Scenario").exec( Login.login )
  setUp(
    scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(100) during(20 seconds) )
        .protocols(httpConf)
   )
  object Login{
    val login = exec(http("Login")
            .get("/auth/login")
        )
 }
```

It give me that error message: 
`21:24:23.863 [WARN ] i.g.h.a.ResponseProcessor - Request 'Login' failed: j.n.ConnectException: Failed to open a socket.` what does that mean?

Comment: Is that the only message you received? As in - just THAT ONE message, or more of the same? If more, try decreasing the number of injected users to, say, 1. constantUsersPerSec(1) - See what happens.